# How to add emoji to ProseMirror?

Tags: wysiwyg, prose-mirror

I started to use prosemirror, but I am struggling with finding extensions for it. Even basic extensions as tags, mentions or emoji are hard to find. Am I missing something with this editor? I understood that it is quite mature (trying to drop draft in favor of it), but I might miss something here.

Answer (score 5):

ProseMirror *is* a mature framework, but it isn't as easy to drag and drop as Draft.js is because you *will* have to build out your own nodes for emojis, tags, mentions, etc.

Initially it's going to take a lot of documentation reading, but once you have a firm grasp, building those will be easy.

Let's take emojis for example. We can adapt the dinosaur example from here: https://prosemirror.net/examples/dino/.

First, we will have to define a NodeSpec (https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#model.NodeSpec) for emojis.

```js
const EmojiSpec = {
      attrs: {char: {}}, // dynamic values here
      inline: true,
      group: "inline",
      draggable: false,
      selectable: false,
      parseDOM: [{ // how does prosemirror recognize an emoji if its being pasted from clipboard?
        tag: "img[emoji]",
        getAttrs: (dom: HTMLImageElement) => {
          return {char: dom.getAttribute("alt")};
        }
      }],
      toDOM: (node: PMNode) => { // how should prosemirror render the emoji based on the node values?
        return ['img', {class: "emoji", draggable: "false", alt: node.attrs.char}]
      },
}
```

This is a loose implementation. In production, you'd want to compute an image `src` based on the `node.attrs.char` value like so

```js
      toDOM: (node: PMNode) => {
        const src = getImageSrc(node.attrs.char)
        return ['img', {class: "emoji", draggable: "false", alt: node.attrs.char, src}]
      },
```

Once you have this emoji NodeSpec, you want to combine that with the rest of your custom nodes (like tags mentions) and marks (link, italic, bold) to make a Schema which you plug into the editor. Follow rest of the dinosaur tutorial from here.

Best of luck!

If you're still stuck, I would highly recommend looking at libraries which build upon ProseMirror like tiptap and rich-markdown-editor to see ProseMirror is integrated and used.